# NumPy array of indexing arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I have a NumPy array with shape (300, 500). Consider this as an image with size `(300, 500)` and there are 100 objects on it that I want to fill each of them with a different value.

```py
image = np.zeros((300, 500))
```

I have bounding-box coordinates (x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max) for each of these objects. Then I create indexing arrays using these bounding-box coordinates.

```py
array_of_x_indexing_arrays = []
array_of_y_indexing_arrays = []

for obj in objects:
   x_indices, y_indices = np.mgrid[obj.x_min: obj.x_max + 1, obj.y_min: obj.y_max + 1]
   x_indices, y_indices = x_indices.ravel(), y_indices.ravel()
   array_of_x_indexing_arrays.append(x_indices)
   array_of_y_indexing_arrays.append(y_indices)
```

Then, I want to assign a different value to image for each of these objects. I stored them the values for each object in an array with shape `(100,)`

```py
data = np.array((100,))
# Assume that I filled data such as
# data[0] = 10
# data[1] = 2
# ...
# data[99] = 3
```

Then what I want to do is following

```py
for i in range(len(objects)):
   image[array_of_y_indexing_arrays[i], array_of_x_indexing_arrays[i]] = data[i]
```

But I want to do this in NumPy way, I have tried the following but does not work

```py
image[array_of_y_indexing_arrays, array_of_x_indexing_arrays] = data
```

Comment: Well, this certainly works:  `image[30:60,20:90] = pixel`.  You just need to convert your rectangles into ranges.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yeah but I need to have array of slices (or ranges). I mean, let's say for object1, I want to do this `image[30:60, 20:90] = 2` and for object2  `image[50:85, 0:10] = 4`. How can I do this in a vectorized way, simultaneously?

Comment: You can't do it simultaneously.  It's going to take a loop.

Comment: you can use variable `image[y1:y2, x1:x2] = value` and then you can get values from  list or array and assign to variables `y1,y2,x1,x2,value` - but it may need `for`-loop

Comment: see accepted solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66896138/python-numpy-insert-2d-array-into-bigger-2d-array-on-given-posiiton